# How to show new column from datarow?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   lstData.Add(new Tablelist() 
   { 
      process = row["process"] + "", 
      Event = row["Event"] + "", 
      status = row["status"] + "" 
   });                            
}

// assign the lstData to the gridview..

//Bind data in the Gridview
GridViewShow.DataSource = lstData;
GridViewShow.DataBind();
```

currently its showing the data with 3 column :process, event ,status...in my status column there is stated pass and fail ..how can i form another table to show 2 column of my pass and fail....please guide...i stuck

Comment: another datatable with 2 columns called "pass" "fail" . where the pass and fail is inside 'status column' i just want to split become 2 columns of pass and fail .. to be display in new tablelist..thank you..

Comment: If it is, then you should only show one checkbox column instate of `status` column which will be true if status has true value for pass else false if status has fail true value, also mention `pass` and `fail` column is of what type, string or bool?